# Create a python list from a list imported from Googlesheets using gspread

Tags: python, python-3.x, google-sheets, gspread

I am working on a project for a course to create a command line interface using Python. I have created a pay calculator and want to display previous pay data that's been entered into a Googlesheet using gspread.

I have imported the data into a list:

`all_previous_pay_data = SHEET.worksheet('pay').get_all_values()`

I want the user to then input a Dealer ID which exists in the first column of the sheet that:

```
dealer_id = input("Enter Dealer ID here to start:\n")
```

Want I then want to happen is all previous pay data for people with the inputed ID will be printed to the console. I have tried the following:

```
all_previous_pay_data = SHEET.worksheet('pay').get_all_values()
dealer_pay_data = [pay for pay in all_previous_pay_data if dealer_id == SHEET.worksheet('pay').col_values(1)]
        print(dealer_pay_data)
```

I am getting an empty list.

Please could you someone help me with a solution to pull all rows of data if the column with the dealer ID matches the dealer ID inputted by the user?

Comment: In your question, I think that when you provide your sample Spreadsheet as an image and the sample output values you expect, it will help users think of the solution.

Comment: You are comparing `dealer_id` with the result from `SHEET.worksheet('pay').col_values(1)` dealer I'd is a single value and the col_values is a list that will not work. You might not get it in a single comprehension list, but using a proper `for x in list` then if you find the dealer Id in this line keep the pay. Otherwise keep iterating.